# Get contacts by phonenumber using gdata-contacts

Tags: java, gdata, google-contacts-api

I am trying to use Contacts query parameters reference. See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#contacts-query-parameters-reference

I am building the query like this:

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");

Query query = new Query(feedUrl);

query.setMaxResults(1111);

query.setStringCustomParameter("phoneNumber", "123456789");
```

But Google API is returning all contacts while I just want the contact who has the 123456789 number.

Is it possible to get a google contact by phone number?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing query to https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?q="6785555455" . I tried this in [oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?code=4/RGddKrNdR87RMgEi6DvVk_GscFAwKxjVlky6yowqizk#) and was able to retrieve contact who has matching phone number 6785555455. Here is the response:

```
<gd:name>
  <gd:fullName>Hello</gd:fullName>
  <gd:givenName>Hi</gd:givenName>
</gd:name>
<gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile"  uri="tel:+91-1234-222-321">(678)-555-5455</gd:phoneNumber>
<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false"    href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/guntupalliswathi%40gmail.com/b  ase/6"/>
</entry>
</feed>
```

check this [link](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#Queries) for reference.